# Density plot ggplot error returning missing aesthetic error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a `Density Plot` for the class values for each of the four bands in a data frame. Now when I try to plot it, `geom_density` returns an error.

How can I fix this?

```
Class   Red         Blue        Green       MSAVI
GRND    0.254241894 0.110313222 0.159854318 -0.216356573
SHRB    0.081104881 0.042177001 0.069155373 0.127747396
TREE    0.092559343 0.050581477 0.083049583 0.08810719
WATR    0.09050273  0.034529627 0.060246605 -0.182429743

dput(profiles)
structure(list(Class = structure(1:4, .Label = c("GRND", 
"SHRB", "TREE", "WATR"), class = "factor"), Red = c(0.254241893688838, 
0.081104880819718, 0.0925593425830205, 0.0905027302602927), Blue = c(0.110313221812248, 
0.0421770010143518, 0.050581476961573, 0.034529626990358), Green = c(0.159854317704837, 
0.0691553726792336, 0.0830495829383532, 0.0602466048051914), 
    MSAVI = c(-0.216356573005517, 0.12774739585196, 
    0.0881071899784729, -0.182429743309816)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code

```
library(tidyverse)

# Read data
profiles = read.csv("~/profiles.csv")

# Make a DF
Profiles_df = as.data.frame(Profiles)

# Density Histograms
Profiles_df %>%  pivot_longer(
        cols = -"Class"
) %>% ggplot(
        mapping = aes(x = name, y = value, color = Class, group = Class)
) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.75) + 
  geom_vline(data = . %>% group_by(Class) %>% summarise(grp.mean = mean(value)),
             aes(x=grp.mean, color = Class), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('cyan', 'burlywood', 'darkgreen', 'blue'),
                    name = "class") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("gray", "#CD853F", "#3CB371", "#33CEFF")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray", size = 0.5),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "gray", size = 0.5),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "Value",
       y = "Density",
       title = "Density histograms of spectral profiles",
       subtitle = "Vertical lines represent mean group values")
```

Error

```
Error: geom_density requires the following missing aesthetics: x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x
```

Below is what I am trying to produce with my data, please note that since the data is different, the information in the plot below doesn't match with my data. It is just to give an idea.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the density plot of `value`, not `name`.
Try setting `aes(x = value)` and also `xintercept` instead of `x` for `geom_vline`:

```r
profiles %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -"Class") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, fill = Class, group = Class)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  geom_vline(data = . %>% group_by(Class) %>% summarise(grp.mean = mean(value)),
             aes(xintercept = grp.mean, color = Class), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, any idea as to why my [plot's](https://app.box.com/s/fizh5mczuhocauclfxr8yjf2yd29xrrn) `Class` legend is different than yours? My Class legend is mixing colors for some reason. Is this a glitch?

Comment: It may just be the height of your plot compared to mine.  The dashed lines can get wonky based on dimensions.